# Calculate sum of one column based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame:

```
Y  X1  X2  X3
1   1   0  1
1   0   1  1
0   1   0  1
0   0   0  1
1   1   1  0
0   1   1  0
```

I want sum over all rows in `Y` column based on other columns that equal to `1`, which is `sum(Y=1|Xi =1`). For example, for column `X1`, `s1 = sum(Y=1|Xi =1) =1 + 0 +1+0 =2`

```
Y  X1   
1   1   

0   1    

1   1    
0   1
```

For `X2` column, the `s2 = sum(Y=1|Xi =1) = 0 +1+0 =1`

```
    Y   X2  

    0   1   

    1   1    
    0   1
```

For `X3` column, the `s3 = sum(Y=1|Xi =1) = 1+1 +0+0 =2`

```
    Y    X3
    1    1
    1    1
    0    1
    0    1
```

I have a rough idea to use `apply(df, 2, sum)` for the column of the dataframe, but I have no idea how to subset each column based on `Xi`, then calculate the `sum` of `Y.` Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you ok doing this manually per column, or do you want it automatically done for a whole bunch of columns?

Comment: I want it altomatically done for a whole bunch of columns

Comment: Fyi, you might want to `dput` your data next time, for easier reproducibility for your answerers. Some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `colSums` and count when Y*X is equal to 1. I think there's an error in your desired output for X2 column. Row 2 and 5 contain 1 for Y and X2. The sum should be 2.

```
x=read.table(text="Y  X1  X2  X3
1   1   0  1
1   0   1  1
0   1   0  1
0   0   0  1
1   1   1  0
0   1   1  0",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

colSums(x[,-1]*x[,1])

X1 X2 X3 
 2  2  2
```

You can also use `crossprod(x[,1],as.matrix(x[,-1]))`

```
     X1 X2 X3
[1,]  2  2  2
```

Comment: Or `x[,1] %*% as.matrix(x[,-1])`

Answer (score 6):

There are numerous ways to do this. One is getting a subset based on the column you want:

```
sum(df[df$X1==1,]$Y)
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more approach that you could modify to sum elements corresponding to 1, 0, or some other value.

```
sapply(x[,-1], function(a) sum(x$Y[a == 1]))
#X1 X2 X3 
# 2  2  2
```